Modules spring.jcl and org.apache.commons.logging export package org.apache.commons.logging to module spring.data.jdbc'
In one of my java spring projects with the following pom (extract):
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.4</version>
  <relativePath/>
</parent>


<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <optional>true</optional>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
  </dependency>
        
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.mariadb.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mariadb-java-client</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.vaadin.external.google</groupId>
        <artifactId>android-json</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.validation-api</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.spotbugs</groupId>
    <artifactId>spotbugs-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>4.8.6</version>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>

I got the following error message:
[INFO] --- surefire:3.5.0:test (default-test) @ server ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[WARNING] Corrupted channel by directly writing to native stream in forked JVM 1. See FAQ web page and the dump file C:\MyProject\target\surefire-reports\2024-09-28T14-37-03_544-jvmRun1.dumpstream

When looking into the mentioned surefire-report file I see:
Stream 'Error occurred during initialization of boot layer'.
Stream 'java.lang.module.ResolutionException: Modules spring.jcl and org.apache.commons.logging export package org.apache.commons.logging to module spring.data.jdbc'.

After checking all dependencies I found:
jcl-over-slf4j-2.0.16.jar:
org.apache.commons.logging.*
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.*

and spring-jcl-6.1.13.jar:
org.apache.commons.logging.*
org.apache.commons.logging.impl.*

So we have a split package which is not allowed within the java module system.
Also I think that both packages are not really part of the org.apache.commons.logging domain.
So my question is how to solve this problem? Is it a bug within the spring framework?
